# How to export backlog items from scrum to agile template in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs-2015, devops

I need a clarification on how to export backlog items from scrum process to agile process in TFS 2015.

The hierarchy is Epic --> feature --> task --> bug......
based on these backlog items need to be export from scrum and import to agile process template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use Excel to export and import the work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel) between Scrum and Agile.

Please follow below steps to do that:

1. Create a **Tree of work items** query for the work items you want to
   export in ***Scrum project***.
2. Open the query in Visual Studio, Click **Column Options** to select
   which column you want to display/export, then select **Open Query in
   Microsoft Excel**.
3. Create a same hierarchy for the work items as the Scrum project in
   your Agile project, then create  a **Tree of work items** query.
4. Open the Agile query in Visual Studio, Click **Column Options** to
   select same columns as the Scrum query (Basically select the columns you want to import ), then select **Open Query in Microsoft Excel**.
5. Copy the work items from ***Scrum to Agile*** in excel (Copy the contents
   from step2 to step4, please make sure that they have same columns
   for both query, you may need to edit some of columns to match the
   Agile values, as Scrum and Agile have different process workflow)
6. Just click the '**Publish**' to import the work items to Agile once
   complete the modification.

[image]

Comment: @sandeep s , is the workaround helpful for you? any update?