# VSTS: Copying a task form one PBI to another PBI

Tags: azure-devops

Is there any way to copy **Tasks** from a PBI to another PBI in VSTS? I haven't found any resources in the VSTS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/index?view=vsts) and from searching on google.

I know how to copy a PBI but if that PBI has some tasks, they will not be copied.

Comment: I think it might be good to remove the [tag:scrum] and [tag:agile] tags since the question really isn't about either of those subjects. This question is very specifically tied to the mechanics of a specific software product (and off topic, since it's not really programming related)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have removed those tags :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to copy the sub-tasks:

1. Create a **Tree of work items** query.
2. Open the query with Microsoft Excel
3. In Excel, copy the Task contents from one PBI to another following the Tree
   hierarchy
4. Click the '**Publish**' to import the work items once complete the
   modification.

You can reference my answer in this similar thread :https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493445/7466674

Please see [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=vsts) for details.